# queueing and batching requests using java

Tags: java, queue, jms

I want to use some mechanism to do something like this - I have a application server getting request to process orders. One request can have one order or two orders. To process the order the application will need to make a call to outside vendor, vendor can process at the most 5 orders at a time. I want to create a component that will batch maximum up to 5 orders if available and fire one request to the vendor and then when I get the response re-distribute the reponse to the appropriate request. The component would wait, say, 2 seconds before firing a batch request ones the first request arrives.

I thought of using JMS but in JMS a consumer will process the message (order) as soon as it arrives and a consumer processes one message at a time. I am thinking of usinga regular queue (ArrayBlockingQueue) and batch up the orders before firing using a ScheduledTimerTask. Does anybody have any ideas - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try implementing this solution? Did you encounter any specific problems?

Answer (score 2):

Most of what you describe can be done with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). It can be configured to throttle, to batch, and forward request.

The [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) does what "max wait for X messages and then forward request"

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have never used Apache Camel, I have heard this ESB kind of solutions are slow - do you know of any performance issues. Do you know if the same thing can be done using Mule - they are thinking of using Mule in our company for something else. I am thinking they may not want to support both Camel and Mule.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say that Camel is slow, but hearing that you ask about that sounds a bit odd in this situation. Everything will be "slow" if you wait for a certain amount of messages before you send a request (in the context of latency, not throughput)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from using JMS. Just set a timeout on the operation that fetches from your queue, and when you have 5 messages or a timeout, you process the batch.

Comment: If I use JMS, I think each message will be processed by a separate consumer depending on how many I configure. If I set a timeout in the consumer, how will it help if it does not receive the second message and another consumer receives it

Comment: For example, have a look at jmsTemplate in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/ Have some code call the receive method 5 times, collect the messages in a collection of some sort, make a batch of it, and call the api